# django-allauth: how to redirect to previous page after login

Tags: django, django-urls, django-allauth, django-settings

I'm using django-allauth. I can successfully redirect it to home page by adding this in settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
```

But is there anyway I can redirect it to previous page?

Comment: The first method I can think of that has worked for me before is to write a function for each individual route that can possibly prompt a login and redirect them to their respected view. It sounds complicated as I write it so I hope someone finds a better method

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for should actually work out of the box by using the *redirect field*, which is `next` by default:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.get_redirect_field_name

The view that is checking for the access permission and redirecting to the login form only needs to pass the URL the user was previously on. If that field is present, the user will be redirected to that particular page after logging in.

How are you restricting login? I assume you're not passing `next`? The `@login_required` decorator and the `LoginRequiredMixin` for class-based views both set `next` by default.

This is what the docs say about how LoginView handles POST requests:

> If called via POST with user submitted credentials, it tries to log the user in. If login is successful, the view redirects to the URL specified in `next`. If `next` isn’t provided, it redirects to `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` (which defaults to `/accounts/profile/`).